# Is there any difference for JVM at these two Java lines:

Tags: java, if-statement

Reviewing a changes of old piece of code, I saw a pretty interesting change. There is the difference:

```
if(retValue.equals("") || retValue == null){

if(retValue == null || retValue.equals("")){
```

Any suggestions? What is the difference to JVM?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `||` and `&&` operators are "lazy": the JVM will stop its evaluation of the expression as soon as it is certain of the result.

- In the case of `||`, it will stop as soon as one of the operands is true ==> whole expression is then true.
- In the case of `&&`, it will stop as soon as one of the operands is false ==> whole expression is then false.

Quote from the [JLS #15.24](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.24) (emphasis mine):

> The conditional-or operator `||` operator is like `|` (§15.22.2), but **evaluates its right-hand operand only if the value of its left-hand operand is false**.

Comment: +1 for explanation of this behavior, which is called [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

Answer (score 5):

Of course. There is a clear difference. For example first one will cause NullPointerException in the case of retValue being null.

Comment: -1 explaining why should help making clear why this happens. cfr short circuit evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

OR returns true if either statement is true.
This means that the if will only check the first statement (example,  in the second line of code)

```
retValue == null
```

and won't check the second, if the first is true. This means that the first line of code may mean a NullPointerException, if retValue is null, but the second won't have a NullPointerException, for the same input.